Kustomize patch doesn't patch base values - GKE Managed Certs
I'm trying to "templatize" the K8s manifests I currently use to generate my Google managed certificates on GKE. When I run kustomize build it runs successfully, but regardless of what patching type I use, the returned yaml only shows the base configuration, none of the patched values are reflected in the build output.  I've tried both strategic merge patching and JSON6902 patching.  I've tried including the path to a patch file as well as doing it directly in the kustomization.yaml using both patches: and patchesJson6902: as well as applying kustomize edit fix and results are all the same.  The files below are my most recent attempt using patchesJson6902: and a kustomization.yaml in-line patch.
Kustomize v5.5.0 & v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
(same results with kubectl included kustomize version)
I have the following file layout:
base
|--managed-cert.yaml
|--kustomization.yaml
overlays
|--newenv
   |--kustomization.yaml

File Contents:
managed-cert.yaml
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: some-managed-cert
  namespace: ""
spec:
  domains:
    - ""

kustomization.yaml (base)
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
- managed-cert.yaml

kustomization.yaml (overlay)
(Edit - changed target version to reflect suggestion below, no change in behavior)
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
- ../../base
namespace: new-env

patchesJson6902:
  - target:
      group: networking.gke.io/v1
      version: v1
      kind: ManagedCertificate
      name: managed-cert
    patch: |-
     - op: replace
       path: /metadata/name
       value: new-cert-name
     - op: replace
       path: /spec/domains/-
       value: new.domain.name  

kustomize build output:
# Warning: 'patchesJson6902' is deprecated. Please use 'patches' instead. Run 'kustomize edit fix' to update your Kustomization automatically.
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: some-managed-cert
  namespace: new-env
spec:
  domains:
  - ""

As you can see the namspace transformation is happening but nothing else is.

Take off the /v1 from the group as it is matched in the version, like thomas said make sure the name is the same, and remove the /- from the path for the domain name.  See if my example below works
patchesJson6902:
  - target:
      group: networking.gke.io
      version: v1
      kind: ManagedCertificate
      name: some-managed-cert
    patch: |-
      - op: replace
        path: /metadata/name
        value: new-cert-name
      - op: replace
        path: /spec/domains
        value: new.domain.name 


Thanks Cody, this eventually fixed it.  Adding /v1 to group will break it (even the trailing slash will break it) and the /- (or even just the /) in  /spec/domain break it as well.

Your patch does not match since you specify a version v1beta1 while the ManagedCertificate is defined using version v1.
Also the name does not match, the object has 'some-managed-cert' and the patch targets 'managed-cert'

Hi Thomas!  Thanks for the response and good eye!  I update the API version to match and still get the same results.  I'll update the question to reflect that.... if I can

I have updated the answer as well

Thanks Thomas! Yep both of those things were definitely part of the issue.  Also found a couple more things that was breaking it as well though, so going to post answer including all the things that finally fixed, including yours here.  Thanks again!
